# How to get current process name in linux?

Tags: c, linux

How can I get the process name in C? The same name, which is in `/proc/$pid/status`. I do not want to parse that file. Is there any programmatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's either pointed to by the `argv[0]` or indeed you can read `/proc/self/status`. Or you can use `getenv("_")`, not sure who sets that and how reliable it is.

Comment: Note that `getenv("_")` appears to return the process originally started by the shell -- if I call it in a process started by `make`, I see "/usr/bin/make", rather than my process name. This means that it's probably set by the shell.

Comment: _ is set by the shell.

Answer (score 45):

If you're on using a glibc, then:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <errno.h>

extern char *program_invocation_name;
extern char *program_invocation_short_name;
```

See program_invocation_name(3)

Under most Unices, `__progname` is also defined by the libc.
The sole portable way is to use `argv[0]`

Answer (score 17):

You can use `__progname`. However it is not better than `argv[0]` as it may have portability issues. But as you do not have access to `argv[0]` it can work as follows:-

```
extern char *__progname;
printf("\n%s", __progname);
```

Answer (score 5):

I often make use of following call,

```
char* currentprocname = getprogname();
```

Comment: That's BSD-specific. You can get it on Linux with `libbsd`, but it's not part of libc as it is on FreeBSD or OS X.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the value of `argv[0]` which was passed to `main`. This should be the name under which your process was invoked.

Comment: Unfortunatelly in this case I dont have access to argv[0]

Comment: @Mariusz Then you're going to have to go through proc - although I recommend `/proc/self/cmdline`.

Comment: @Mariusz, You can also try `getenv("_")` though I'm not sure how reliable it is.

Answer (score 3):

This is a version that works on macOS, FreeBSD and Linux.

```
#if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__FreeBSD__)
const char * appname = getprogname();
#elif defined(_GNU_SOURCE)
const char * appname = program_invocation_name;
#else
const char * appname = "?";
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot access argv[] in main(), because you are implementing a library, you can have a look at my answer on a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471553/access-command-line-arguments-without-using-char-argv-in-main/24718544#24718544).

It basically boils down into giving you access to argc, argv[] and envp[] outside of main().
Then you could, as others have already correctly suggested, use argv[0] to retrieve the process name.

Comment: or you could look at /proc/self/cmdline

Answer (score 1):

for posterity, a version that's more C++-ish and works also on MSVC:

https://godbolt.org/z/sh3TnM

```
#define FMT_HEADER_ONLY
#include <fmt/format.h>

std::string get_current_process_name()
{
    #if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__FreeBSD__)
        return getprogname();
    #elif defined(_GNU_SOURCE)
        return program_invocation_name;
    #elif defined(_WIN32)
        return __argv[0];
    #else
        return "?";
    #endif
}

int main()
{
    fmt::print("whatsmyname: {}\n", get_current_process_name());
    return 0;
}

// msvc output:
// whatsmyname: C:\Users\<user>\source\repos\Project6\Debug\Project6.exe
```