# How to get your process name in qt?

Tags: c++, qt

How to get your (this, this application currently running) process name in qt?

Comment: Define "process name". Do you mean the file name of the executable?

Answer (score 7):

I think you're looking for [QCoreApplication::applicationPid()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#applicationPid).

Comment: PID is not the name. Process ID and Process Name are different attributes.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get the name of the executable (that is, the string normally kept in `argv[0]`), you *might* get that by reading the first element of [`QCoreApplication::arguments()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#arguments).

On Unix, this only works if you initialized your `Q(Core)Application` correctly:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    //...
    return app.exec();
}
```

**Edit:** Actually, it might be better to call [`QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#applicationFilePath) to get the full path of the executable. Given its full path, you can easily get the name of the executable using [`QFileInfo::fileName()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html#fileName).

Comment: Or QFileInfo( QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath() ).fileName() for the filename of the executable.

Comment: @Frank: Thanks, I added that to my answer.

Comment: This approach might work for applications that you wrote. But keep in mind that [a process can change it's name during runtime](https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=66443&lngWId=1), even though it is not recommended. So relying on the executable name might not be the best idea. It's best to trust the native API for the job.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there's **no such thing in Qt**.

You'll have to use the native API of the platform you are working with to retrieve this information.

**Windows**: Check [`GetCurrentProcessId()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683180%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [How to get Process Name in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4570174/176769)

**Linux**: [How to get current process name in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097201/how-to-get-current-process-name-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Use the arg first part

```
   QStringList args = QCoreApplication::instance()->arguments();
    args.takeFirst();
```