# how to get process name from c program?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

In C program in linux, we can use `getpid()` and `getppid()` system call to get the pid and ppid of a process,

Similarly is there any system call to get name of a process/current process?

Comment: I would fetch the process list (using `ps`) and match on the pid.

Answer (score 5):

You can have a look at the `/proc/$pid/cmdline` file (open it like a normal file and read the zero-byte-delimited command line from it).

That's the way the Unix tool `ps` does it on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

one simple way to know the current executable name is `argv[0]`, which tells you the name of the current executable in C.

Answer (score 0):

More solutions can be found here: [How to get current process name in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097201/how-to-get-current-process-name-in-linux)

I implemented the solution using the `program_invocation_name` variable.