# Pass command line argument to a sub function

Tags: c, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have a C program main routine which calls heirarchically several levels of functions. Eg :

```
main -> MyFunc -> MySubFunc -> MySub2Func
```

and I have a condition in MySub2Func which needs to be checked against a command line argument. Eg:

```
if (myvar == argv[1])
```

Other than passing argv as a parameter to subfunction , is there any other way I could acheive this. (because I need to do this in several functions lying at different heirarchical levels)

Each of the sub-functions lie in different C files. My aim is to perform a debug by temporarily checking a particular local variable against a cmd line argument (and taking further actions accordingly) .. hence modifying the entire heirarchy is unfortunately not desirable for my purpose.

---

[update from comment]

sorry that I forgot to mention .. i am trying to perform a debug by temporarily checking a particular local variable against a cmd line argument (and taking further actions accordingly) .. hence modifying the entire heirarchy is unfortunately not desirable for my purpose ..

Comment: Is having global variables an option?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2471553/612920

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common approach is to "[decouple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29)" the two; the functions further down the call tree really shouldn't care or know about `main()`'s arguments, i.e. the command argument vector itself.

Instead, it should be abstracted into application-specific options, which are passed from `main()`, which parses the options out of the command line arguments, down to all application-specific functions that need them.

Comment: sorry that I forgot to mention .. i am trying to perform a debug by temporarily checking a particular local variable against a cmd line argument (and taking further actions accordingly) .. hence modifying the entire heirarchy is unfortunately not desirable for my purpose ..

Answer (score 2):

You might use global variables that are set in the `main()` function:

```
int    g_argc;
char **g_argv;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    g_argc = argc;
    g_argv = argv;

    MyFunc();

}

...

void MyFunc() {
  MySubFunc();
}

...

void MySubFunc() {
  MySub2Func();
}

...

void MySub2Func() {
   if (myvar == g_argv[1]) {
     do_the_thing();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As unwind said, the functions further down the chain should really not know anything about main's arguments. You should parse the command line arguments once setting the program's configuration. Additionally you should provide query functions for this configuration e.g.

```
/* --- config.c */

typedef struct {
   int debug_enabled;
} config_t;

static config_t configuration;

int debug_enabled() {
    return configuration->debug_enabled;
}

void initialize_config() {
    /* set default parameters */
}

int set_config_from_cmd(int argc, char** argv){
    /* parse CMD parameters and set config */
}


/* --- main.c */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    initialize_config();
    if ( set_config_from_cmd(argc, argv) == -1 ) {
        exit(-1);
    }

    /* do stuff, call functions */
}


int myfunction() {
    if ( debug_enabled() ) {
        printf("debug!");
    }
    /* do stuff */
}
```

Notice that I put the configuration related stuff into a separate file in order to hide the internals of the configuration structure. Only the interface e.g. `debug_enabled()` etc is exposed.

Answer (score 0):

[for debugging]

Put this in a header included by all modules involved:

```
extern int g_argc;
extern char ** g_argv;
```

Define `g_argc` and `g_argv` globally in the main module

```
int g_argc = 0;
char ** g_argv = NULL;
```

Then in `main()` just do

```
int main(int argv, char ** argv)
{
  g_argc = argc;
  g_argv = argv;
```

and access `g_argc` and `g_argv` from the modules in question.

Comment: thanks .. i tried your suggestion and it looks exactly like the simple hack i was looking for .. visual studio gives out "unresolved externals" error upon compiling ( when I do "go to definition" at extern declaration in sub-routine file, it takes me to the main function declaration though! )

Comment: Did you do a full rebuild, that is 1st "clean project" and then "build project"? @user3698698

Comment: yes i had performed a rebuild :-| the main and sub-function lies in different modules .. would that make a difference?

Comment: Did you define `g_argc` and `g_argv` globally, that is **not** in side the `main()` function, but **out**side? @user3698698

Comment: yes g_argv is defined globally (*out* side the main) .. i dont need argc and hence havent used g_argc