# How to change the name of a haskell process under linux

Tags: linux, haskell

I am trying to change the name of a running process under linux. In C, I would just modify `argv[0]` in-place, but how can I do that from haskell? I noticed that ghc has a primitive called `getProgArgv`:

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "getProgArgv"
    getProgArgv :: Ptr CInt -> Ptr (Ptr CString) -> IO ()
```

but I tried with that and it didn't work. Also, I am aware of `prctl(PR_SET_NAME,"...")` but that only changes the current thread's name, and most tools (such as `ps` and `htop`) do not use that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I came up with an ugly hack that seems to work. It based on a idea borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24718544). We have to use an auxiliary c file:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>

char *argv0 = 0;

static void capture_argv0(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    argv0 = argv[0];
}
__attribute__((section(".init_array"))) void (*p_capture_argv0)(int, char*[]) = &capture_argv0;

void set_prog_name(char *name) {
    if (!argv0) return;
    size_t len = strlen(argv0);
    strncpy(argv0, name, len);
    prctl(PR_SET_NAME, name);
}
```

This relies on the `section(".init_array")` attribute that tells gcc to register `capture_argv0` as an initialization function. This means that it will be executed before `main`. We use it to make a copy of the `argv[0]` pointer and store it as a global variable. Now we can call `set_prog_name` from haskell.