# argc and argv for functions other than main

Tags: c, function, program-entry-point, argv, argc

If I write a function such as this:

```
void myfunc(const int argc, const char *argv[])
```

Will argc and argv automatically get their values from command line arguments, or will they need to be passed in their values from main?

Comment: It must be deliberately passed to the function. E.g `myfunc(argc-1, argv+1);`

Comment: Only main()  get values from command line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access command line arguments without using char \*\*argv in main](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471553/access-command-line-arguments-without-using-char-argv-in-main)

Answer (score 3):

argc and argv must be passed, such as:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
   myfunc(argc, argv);
   return(0);
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

No, nothing special happens if you call a function's arguments `argc` and `argv`. The caller has to pass them, like any other arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Argument names are not significant *per se*. You can write main like this:

```
int main(int count, char *array[]) {...}
```

if you like. `main` is a *special* function because it is the default entry point of a C program and that command-line arguments values are passed to it, that's all.

Declaring/defining a function as:

```
void myfunc(int argc,char *argv[]) {...}
```

is exactly the same as:

```
void myfunc(int foo,char *bar[]) {...}
```

and such a function can be called from any (possible) point you like with any (acceptable) values you like.